# Calculate Similarity of Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, classification, sparse-matrix

I am using Python with numpy, scipy and scikit-learn module.

I'd like to classify the arrays in very big sparse matrix. (100,000 * 100,000)

The values in the matrix are equal to 0 or 1. The only thing I have is the index of value = 1.

```
a = [1,3,5,7,9] 
b = [2,4,6,8,10]
```

which means

```
a = [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
b = [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
```

How can I change the index array to the sparse array in scipy ?

How can I classify those array quickly ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: this makes me wonder, would it be possible to just make the entire matrix non-sparse, since all the values are 0 or 1 anyways, so instead of 64bit per float or so, you only use one bit each?  ( i know this doesnt solve your problem or so, but your question made me come up with this question)

Comment: What kind of similarity do you want to compute? Why do you need the sparse matrix, instead of just using the indices? How about something simple like len(set(a) & set(b)) / float(len(a))?

Comment: Actually, I'd like to group those array from the similarity. For example [1,1,1,0] is more like [1,1,0,0] but inverse with [0,0,0,1]. Since the number of columns and rows are large. I dont' know is there any method could do it sooner.

Comment: How many groups are you trying for -- 10 x 10k, 100 x 1k ?  Have you looked through [scikit-learn clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you choose the sparse `coo_matrix` you can create it passing the indices like:

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
import scipy
nrows = 100000
ncols = 100000
row = scipy.array([1,3,5,7,9])
col = scipy.array([2,4,6,8,10])
values = scipy.ones(col.size)
m = coo_matrix((values, (row,col)), shape=(nrows, ncols), dtype=float)
```